# Is it possible to run a multiple client TCP server with no RTOS or it is the only option to code a server like this?

Tags: multithreading, stm32, tcpserver, lwip

I'm trying to develop a TCP server with multiclient connections (~10) on a stm32f207 micrcontroller with its HAL drivers.
Looking at stm32 repository there exists examples of built servers following diferent strategies. But all of them are unique client connection oriented and uses LwIP stack.
I was working with FreeRtos and netconn example with HAL_ETH driver.

I thougth that multithreading could be useful for creating new tcp client connections. Every client has its own thread created by the server. Since I'm getting the application hunged with hardfault or losing the whole connection after some time working I'm wondering if freeRtos is adding a lot of complexity that is unnecessary. Because I 'have read that freertos ask for thread safing functions and HAL drivers doesn't provide thread safing functions. I start to think that FreeRtos may be bad idea for this.

I chose this strategy, in fact, because demo was built for nucleo board hardware and I thought that I could take advantage from the commented featuring: one thread per client.

But now I'm wondering if multiple tcp client connection could be reached and handled by a server non-RTOS implemented. I know that non-freertos based application only can be coded using RAW LWIP api services.

But the qüestion:

**- would RAW with non-RTOS integration be capable of handle a server with multiple client connections? or is it only posible with thread creation?**

**- which of the following option/combination is (for a beginner developer) the best one for implementing a server that handles up to 10 client connections?**

***1.raw with non RTOS***

***2.raw with freertos***

***3.nectonn with freertos***

***4.socket with freertos***

Comment: All of these are possible.  Which is best depends on your preference, there is no right answer.

Comment: Thanks @TomV, so using raw without any RTOS would also be enough for handling multiple tcp connections. Is it?

Comment: LwIP can do this, yes.

Comment: @Suvi_Eu why do you want to write extremely complicated state machine instead of a relatively simple RTOS code?

Comment: First I asked for information to understand which options are because data I read is not clear. Second I've just said that I don't know differences of 4 strategies (the same reason). I couldn't find before any source about the implications of 4 methods. Third is that I think my knowledge on RTOS is limiting this choice. I created 10 client threads from a tcp server demo (provided by ST) and application hangs with hardfault after some time. It also happens using udp server for client connections. So I would like to know about the other options, specially performance and complexity differences.

Comment: @Suvi_Eu demos are not real apps. They do not have to have a production code quality

Comment: I have realized this. Now I'm trying to learn more about LWIP and FreeRtos memory parameters in order to check them and to adjust them if needed.

Comment: I think my server app is not much resource-computing demanging. My server only need to send less than 16 data bytes inside payload field. Incoming requests from clients: no more than 17 bytes at the worst case. Now we are stressing the board with 60 comands (requests with 17 bits of payload)/second per client for testing purpose. When more than 4 clients connect it, we have seen that the maximum ratio achieved by the system is an average of 300/sec. This feature would be fine for us if application doesn't hang 3 hours later. I suspect that hard fault has memory config issue origin.